# Dividir fechas por semana dado el valor de un mes c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo un pequeño gran dilema en el cual consiste que en la aplicación que tengo en desarrollo obtengo los datos de un mes por ejemplo junio que consta del 1 al 30 ,pero ahora tengo que dividirlo en las 5 semanas el cual lo conforma como detallo en la imagen, como podría realizar esto en código? y que me devuelva el día lunes y domingo de cada una de las 5 semanas que conforma ese rango de fecha.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes puntos de reputación que indican que conoces cómo funciona el sitio. Agrega el código que has intentado, si solo dices tengo este deber resuélvanlo, no es bien recibido.

Comment: qué mejor que hacerlo con que cada semana sea una fila de una matriz que coincida con el mes. Saludos

Comment: Nuevamente te invitamos a revisa [ask] y realiza el [tour], saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como me indicaron en sus comentarios tenia que haber indicado algún tipo de código para poder solventar mi duda y bueno aquí traigo la respuesta que me funciona en mi código y me da el resultado esperado.

```
if((int)fecini.DayOfWeek == 1)
            {                    
                tmpff1 = fecini.AddDays(6);
            }
            else if ((int)fecini.DayOfWeek == 2)
            {
                tmpff1 = fecini.AddDays(5);
            }
            else if ((int)fecini.DayOfWeek == 3)
            {
                tmpff1 = fecini.AddDays(4);
            }
            else if ((int)fecini.DayOfWeek == 4)
            {
                tmpff1 = fecini.AddDays(3);
            }
            else if ((int)fecini.DayOfWeek == 5)
            {
                tmpff1 = fecini.AddDays(2);
            }
            else if ((int)fecini.DayOfWeek == 6)
            {
                tmpff1 = fecini.AddDays(1);
            }
            else if ((int)fecini.DayOfWeek == 7)
            {
                tmpff1 = fecini.AddDays(0);
            }

            daP.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FECHAI1", fecini.ToShortDateString());
            daP.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FECHAF1", tmpff1.ToShortDateString());
            DateTime tmpfi2 = tmpff1.AddDays(1);
            daP.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FECHAI2", tmpfi2.ToShortDateString());                
            if ((int)tmpfi2.DayOfWeek == 1)
            {
                tmpff2 = tmpfi2.AddDays(6);
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi2.DayOfWeek == 2)
            {
                tmpff2 = tmpfi2.AddDays(5);
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi2.DayOfWeek == 3)
            {
                tmpff2 = tmpfi2.AddDays(4);
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi2.DayOfWeek == 4)
            {
                tmpff2 = tmpfi2.AddDays(3);
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi2.DayOfWeek == 5)
            {
                tmpff2 = tmpfi2.AddDays(2);
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi2.DayOfWeek == 6)
            {
                tmpff2 = tmpfi2.AddDays(1);
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi2.DayOfWeek == 7)
            {
                tmpff2 = tmpfi2.AddDays(0);
            }
            daP.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FECHAF2", tmpff2.ToShortDateString());
            DateTime tmpfi3 = tmpff2.AddDays(1);
            daP.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FECHAI3", tmpfi3.ToShortDateString());
            if ((int)tmpfi3.DayOfWeek == 1)
            {
                tmpff3 = tmpfi3.AddDays(6);
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi3.DayOfWeek == 2)
            {
                tmpff3 = tmpfi3.AddDays(5);
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi3.DayOfWeek == 3)
            {
                tmpff3 = tmpfi3.AddDays(4);
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi3.DayOfWeek == 4)
            {
                tmpff3 = tmpfi3.AddDays(3);
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi3.DayOfWeek == 5)
            {
                tmpff3 = tmpfi3.AddDays(2);
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi3.DayOfWeek == 6)
            {
                tmpff3 = tmpfi3.AddDays(1);
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi3.DayOfWeek == 7)
            {
                tmpff3 = tmpfi3.AddDays(0);
            }
            daP.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FECHAF3", tmpff3.ToShortDateString());
            DateTime tmpfi4 = tmpff3.AddDays(1);
            daP.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FECHAI4", tmpfi4.ToShortDateString());
            if ((int)tmpfi4.DayOfWeek == 1)
            {
                tmpff4 = tmpfi4.AddDays(6);
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi4.DayOfWeek == 2)
            {
                tmpff4 = tmpfi4.AddDays(5);
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi4.DayOfWeek == 3)
            {
                tmpff4 = tmpfi4.AddDays(4);
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi4.DayOfWeek == 4)
            {
                tmpff4 = tmpfi4.AddDays(3);
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi4.DayOfWeek == 5)
            {
                tmpff4 = tmpfi4.AddDays(2);
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi4.DayOfWeek == 6)
            {
                tmpff4 = tmpfi4.AddDays(1);
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi4.DayOfWeek == 7)
            {
                tmpff4 = tmpfi4.AddDays(0);
            }
            daP.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FECHAF4", tmpff4.ToShortDateString());
            DateTime tmpfi5 = tmpff4.AddDays(1);
            daP.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FECHAI5", tmpfi5.ToShortDateString());
            if ((int)tmpfi5.DayOfWeek == 1 && tmpfi5.Day >= fecfin.Day)
            {
                tmpff5 = fecfin;
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi5.DayOfWeek == 1 && tmpfi5.Day <= fecfin.Day)
            {
                tmpff5 = tmpfi5.AddDays(6);
                if (tmpff5 > fecfin)
                {
                    tmpff5 = fecfin;                       
                }
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi5.DayOfWeek == 2 && tmpfi5.Day >= fecfin.Day)
            {
                tmpff5 = fecfin;
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi5.DayOfWeek == 2 && tmpfi5.Day <= fecfin.Day)
            {
                tmpff5 = tmpfi5.AddDays(5);
                if (tmpff5 > fecfin)
                {
                    tmpff5 = fecfin;
                }
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi5.DayOfWeek == 3 && tmpfi5.Day >= fecfin.Day)
            {
                tmpff5 = fecfin;
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi5.DayOfWeek == 3 && tmpfi5.Day <= fecfin.Day)
            {
                tmpff5 = tmpfi5.AddDays(4);
                if (tmpff5 > fecfin)
                {
                    tmpff5 = fecfin;
                }
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi5.DayOfWeek == 4 && tmpfi5.Day >= fecfin.Day)
            {
                tmpff5 = fecfin;
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi5.DayOfWeek == 4 && tmpfi5.Day <= fecfin.Day)
            {
                tmpff5 = tmpfi5.AddDays(3);
                if (tmpff5 > fecfin)
                {
                    tmpff5 = fecfin;
                }
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi5.DayOfWeek == 5 && tmpfi5.Day >= fecfin.Day)
            {
                tmpff5 = fecfin;
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi5.DayOfWeek == 5 && tmpfi5.Day <= fecfin.Day)
            {
                tmpff5 = tmpfi5.AddDays(2);
                if (tmpff5 > fecfin)
                {
                    tmpff5 = fecfin;
                }
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi5.DayOfWeek == 6 && tmpfi5.Day >= fecfin.Day)
            {
                tmpff5 = fecfin;
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi5.DayOfWeek == 6 && tmpfi5.Day <= fecfin.Day)
            {
                tmpff5 = tmpfi5.AddDays(1);
                if (tmpff5 > fecfin)
                {
                    tmpff5 = fecfin;
                }
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi5.DayOfWeek == 7 && tmpfi5.Day >= fecfin.Day)
            {
                tmpff5 = fecfin;
            }
            else if ((int)tmpfi5.DayOfWeek == 7 && tmpfi5.Day <= fecfin.Day)
            {
                tmpff5 = tmpfi5.AddDays(0);
                if (tmpff5 > fecfin)
                {
                    tmpff5 = fecfin;
                }
            }
            daP.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FECHAF5", tmpff5.ToShortDateString());
```